# How can I scale multiple buttons in click in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

now, I am using

```
public GameObject Button;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Button.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.92f, 0.92f, 0.92f);
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        Button.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

and I used the same code for more buttons onscreen, but when I click one of the buttons, all of them shrink. How can I make them shrink separatly?

Comment: You the buttons event listener, define onPointerDown and up events to them, then you can write this same logic inside them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) listens globally if you press the mouse .. regardless on which or even if on any button ...

---

You could use the interfaces [`IPointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) and [`IPointerUpHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html) like

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public GameObject Button;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Button.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0.92f;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Button.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
}
```

- You will need an [`EventSystem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/EventSystem.html) in your scene
- If your object is not a UI element but a 3D object then you additionally need

  - A Collider on your object
  - A [`PhysicsRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-PhysicsRaycaster.html) component on the `Camera`

---

Alternatively you could also use [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) and [`OnMouseUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html) which are also only called on the specific object that was clicked

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Button;

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Button.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0.92f;
    }

    public void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Button.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
}
```

---

Note: Both require your script to be attached to the same object as the `Collider` or GUIElement